# Plain password in .net core SignInManager Identity

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have user table with plain passwords. I need connect the table into .net core web's AspNetUsers table.How to hash my user table's plain passwords like AspNetUsers's PasswordHash.

How can login with SignInManger plain-text password?

Answer (score 1):

I recently did something like this.  Our legacy system had its own password hashing method.  I needed to covert everything over to asp.net users.

First thing I did was add two new columns to the Application user.  These contain my legacy user password and that hash that was used to create it.

```
public string LegacyPasswordHash { get; set; }
public string LegacyPasswordSalt { get; set; }
```

Then i ran my sql script that copied all of the users in including their legacy password hash and salt.

Then i created a custom SignInManager.

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser> {}
```

In the password check method I test if its a legacy password user and if it is i covert the password that they just sent me over to a asp.net users password and delete their legacy password.   Tip: is to remember to set the user security token on the user table as well this can not be null.  You will have major issues with resting password if it is. As there is a bug in the token validation [2022](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/2022)

This is the section of the code i use for testing and resetting the password.

```
 if (_password.EncodePassword(_user.LegacyPasswordSalt) == _user.LegacyPasswordHash)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.LegacyUserCommand, "Legacy User {_user.Id} migrating password.", _user.Id);
                    await _userManager.AddPasswordAsync(_user, _password);
                    _user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    _user.LegacyPasswordHash = null;
                    _user.LegacyPasswordSalt = null;
                    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(_user);
                    return await new CheckTwoFactorCommand(_logger, _userManager, _user).Execute();
                }
                if (_shouldLockout)
                {
                    _user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(_user);
                    _logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.LegacyUserCommand, "Login failed for Legacy user {_user.Id} invalid password. (LockoutEnabled)", _user.Id);
                    await _userManager.AccessFailedAsync(_user);
                    if (await _userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(_user))
                        return SignInResult.LockedOut;
                }

                _logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.LegacyUserCommand, "Login failed for Legacy user {_user.Id} invalid password", _user.Id);
                return SignInResult.Failed;
```